# Python Bokeh tooltip text formatting

Tags: python, bokeh

The tooltip example presented in the reference guide show the following examples of formatting:

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
    ("radius", "@radius"),
    ("fill color", "$color[hex, swatch]:fill_color"),
    ("foo", "@foo"),
    ("bar", "@bar"),
    ("baz", "@baz{safe}"),
    ("total", "@total{$0,0.00}"
```

The 3 examples `{safe}`, `{$0,0.00}`  and `"$color[hex, swatch]:fill_color"` are not clear: where can i find some documentation on them?

Basically I would like to understand what is possible and what isn't.

At the moment (for instance) I have 1 input that us a very long string (its a newspaper article) that **I would like to format so it only shows the x first characters.**

Other example I have a field `@datetime` that is retrieving its value from a datetime index. At the moment the tooltip displays that value as a `int64` character. How to **use a format tool such as `Timestamp.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")` so that it shows the date time in human readable format?**

But I would like to have a clearer overview of what is possible/how that aspect of bokeh works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this answer was originally posted, new work has gone into Bokeh to make things simpler. A datetime field can be formatted as a datetime directly by the hover tool, by specifying a formatter, e.g.:

```
HoverTool(tooltips=[('label', '@datetime{%F}')],
          formatters={'datetime': 'datetime'})
```

It is no longer necessary to pre-format date fields in the data source as below (although it certainly still works). For more information see [Formatting Tooltip Fields](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields)

---

**OLD ANSWER**:

This is still an open issue for the project:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1239

However, given some other recent work, this should now be fairly easy to implement this feature in a natural way. I have scheduled the task for the next `0.12.6` milestone.

Also, although Bokeh has extensive and rich documentation, there are still occasional gaps. This happens to be one of them, unfortunately. I note that there is an open issue to improve this:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2595

I've updated it to make sure it is also included in the `0.12.6` milestone.

---

In the mean time, your best option is to pre-format the data as you want it to appear in the tooltip in Python. Then add a column to your data source that has the formatted version, the configure the hover tool to display this column:

```
source.data['formatted_date'] = my_pretty_print(source.date['date'])

hover.tooltips = [ ("date", "@formatted_date") ]
```

Comment: When using a pandas dataframe for the ColumnDataSource, I use a similar pattern of adding a column to the dataframe:
```
df['timestamp'] = df['event_time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%A %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

Comment: Tooltip formatting seems to be implemented now. There are tables describing formatting options [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.NumeralTickFormatter.format). Format tooltip data like `@data{format_string}`.